# Spresense拡張ボードから外部器機への電源供給は可能か？

Tags: spresense, usb

Spresense本体にはPCから電源供給しつつ、Spresense拡張ボードのMicroUSB端子から、外部器機へ電源供給できないものでしょうか？
外部器機側はMiniUSB-TypeBメスなので、USB Aメス→miniBオスの変換ケーブルを使って接続していますが、外部器機は反応なし(起動せず)です。

Answer (score 0):

[拡張ボード回路図](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/introduction_ja.html#_spresense_%E6%8B%A1%E5%BC%B5%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89) を見る限り、拡張ボードに載っているのはごく普通の micro-B コネクタです。つまり「外部電源機器→拡張ボード」方向のみの電力受け渡しができる構造ですし、実際回路図を読んでもそうなっています。ということは SP 拡張ボード→他の機器（元発言では外部器機と書いてあるが機器だろう）へ電力受け渡しはできません。

SP 拡張基板から電源を取り出したい場合は JP1 I/O Power SW JP を使うか、または JP3 Power I/F を使えばよさそうです（取ってよい電流値は慎重に検討のこと）

Answer (score 0):

自分は大きな電流が必要なセンサをSpresenseでセンシングするときに、下記のような二股ケーブルを使ってSpresenseとセンサに電源供給をしています。

ご参考になれば。

[UGREEN Micro USB二股ケーブル 2.4A出力対応 (Amazon.co.jp)](https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B071VCTBQQ/)